# Remove duplicate lines in a file that is being used by another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a file called `example.txt` and I want to remove the duplicate lines in this file using my C# application.

My application is multi-threaded, and more than one thread are already accessing the file `example.txt`

I've tried a lot of methods but all of them returns the error:

> The file {0} is already being used by another process.

Comment: If the file is in use by another thread, there isn't much you can do. Attempting to read/write by multiple threads at the same time would cause data corruption. I'd implement a `lock ()` mechanism.

Comment: @FrankerZ - I've tried `lock(locker) {
                File.WriteAllLines(filepath, File.ReadLines(filepath)
                                                        .Where(line => previousLines.Add(line)));
                }` but it is giving the same problem.

Comment: Add a `.ToArray()` after the `.Where()`.

Comment: @FrankerZ - `File.ReadLines(filepath).Where().ToArray` that can't work

Comment: Ok, I got it to work but still the same results :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by specifying file share in your file stream

```
FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It allows you to open file by another process, you still need to implement locking mechanism

Comment: But why did you make it `FileStream s2`, why not `New FileStream` so it can be called immediately on a method?